# Tomcat 7 in Ubuntu or Ubuntu Server?

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, tomcat7, ubuntu-server

I have to install Tomcat 7 in Ubuntu 14.04. Since the procedure is very long, I don't want to make any errors since the beginning. So, the question is: is Ubuntu Server required for installing this device?

Comment: No, the desktop version of Ubuntu is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any issue in installing in either machines. You can as well install this in a normal machine. If you want a one-click install, you can go with `tasksel`.

```
$ sudo apt-get install tasksel
$ sudo tasksel
```

and choose Tomcat Server.